# sails.js query json objects inside table column

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, sails.js, waterline

So this must be a strange question, I want [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) ORM to search something like following

If this is the result for query for the following

```
Venue.findOne({id: 125274827508536}).exec()
```

returns >

```
{
   "id": "125274827508536",
   "attire": "Casual",
   "can_post": false,
   "category": "Restaurant/cafe",
   "category_list": [
      {
         "id": "200742186618963",
         "name": "Vegetarian & Vegan Restaurant"
      },
      {
         "id": "192108214153222",
         "name": "Breakfast & Brunch Restaurant"
      },
      {
         "id": "188296324525457",
         "name": "Sandwich Shop"
      }
   ],
   "checkins": 562,
   "cover": {
      "cover_id": 356427064393310,
      "offset_x": 0,
      "offset_y": 13,
      "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t31.0-8/s720x720/460144_356427064393310_1179113344_o.jpg",
      "id": "356427064393310"
   },
   "culinary_team": "Ramy Abu-Yousef : Owner, Chef\nDallas Jones: Chef",
   "description": "Unique Sandwiches\nDelicious Salads\nHomemade Soups (4 daily)\nFresh Fruit Smoothies\nMilkshakes\nMOUSTACHE WALL OF FAME",
   "general_manager": "Ramy Abu-Yousef & Syndey Friedemann",
   "has_added_app": false,
   "hours": {
      "mon_1_open": "08:00",
      "mon_1_close": "22:00",
      "tue_1_open": "08:00",
      "tue_1_close": "22:00",
      "wed_1_open": "08:00",
      "wed_1_close": "22:00",
      "thu_1_open": "08:00",
      "thu_1_close": "22:00",
      "fri_1_open": "08:00",
      "fri_1_close": "22:00",
      "sat_1_open": "08:00",
      "sat_1_close": "22:00",
      "sun_1_open": "08:00",
      "sun_1_close": "22:00"
   },
   "is_community_page": false,
   "is_published": true,
   "likes": 540,
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/JohnnyBarrs",
   "location": {
      "city": "Queenstown",
      "country": "New Zealand",
      "latitude": -45.032691433795,
      "longitude": 168.66154298959,
      "street": "15 Church Street",
      "zip": "9300"
   },
   "name": "Johnny Barr's",
   "parking": {
      "lot": 1,
      "street": 1,
      "valet": 0
   },
   "payment_options": {
      "amex": 1,
      "cash_only": 0,
      "discover": 0,
      "mastercard": 1,
      "visa": 1
   },
   "phone": "+64 (0)3 409 0169",
   "price_range": "$$ (10-30)",
   "restaurant_services": {
      "delivery": 1,
      "catering": 0,
      "groups": 1,
      "kids": 1,
      "outdoor": 0,
      "reserve": 0,
      "takeout": 1,
      "waiter": 0,
      "walkins": 1
   },
   "restaurant_specialties": {
      "breakfast": 1,
      "coffee": 1,
      "dinner": 1,
      "drinks": 1,
      "lunch": 1
   },
   "talking_about_count": 2,
   "username": "JohnnyBarrs",
   "website": "www.johnnybarrs.com",
   "were_here_count": 562
}
```

Now what I need sails to do is the following

```
Venue.findOne({'restaurant_services': {'delivery': 1}).exec()
```

To return the same object as I have shown above,

Any thoughts please ?

Answer (score 3):

If your adapter is mongo then you can do this out of the box

```
Venue.findOne({'restaurant_services.delivery': 1}).exec()
```

So you should consider your options if you can transform the data into another source to preform this query.

If not and your adapter is SQL based then it is more difficult and would require more information on your use case to decide on the most efficient option.

For instance if you could limit your query to a few indexed fields in a SQL database, you could then use lodash to find your records within your records.

```
Venue.find({/*limiting criteria to bring down the number of results*/}).exec(function(err,results){/* JSON.parse(results) then use lodash to find the final result*/})
```

Another option could be

```
Venue.find({restaurant_services: {contains: 'delivery: 1'}}).exec()
```

that is an out of the box idea, but one that might work.

Again depends deeply on your setup, how its indexed and out of how many venues that one would need to be found.

Comment: Im using sails-mysql adapter.. What other information can I let you to come to a proper function please ?

Comment: Also how can I find a record by checking if one of the objects is empty ? For example sometimes `'restaurant_services' could be just a {}` Please let me know

Comment: It depends. If you want to query the data as a native string inside of the SQL column, and you want to find a null you can do ```{'restaurant_services: {contains: 'delivery: null'}'}```, that assumes you don't find a solution to just transform your data into a new database. Which I recommend.

Comment: Should I worry about sql injections in either when I'm using the Mode.query or ORM ? Or should I always use the _.escape for the values passed from the client ?